# Как редиректнуть на эту же страницу где отправил форму?

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('comment_success', 'Комментарий добавлен!');
redirect('posts/view/$slug'); -> Это не работает...
```

$slug это название статьи

$slug есть у конкретной статьи где расположена форма, а после отправки url Будет posts/comment как мне осуществить тогда после отправки чтобы на туже страницу попасть с конкретной статьёй..?

Comment: может быть двойные кавычки помогут ... `"posts/view/$slug"`

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, ты пытаешься редиректить на статью $slug, которая в момент выполнения кода пуста. Нужно запоминать, откуда пришел юзер;)

Установить URL в сеансе:

```
$this->session->set_userdata('referred_from',current_url());
```

Используй session->userdata , чтобы получить current_url, который ты сохранил в сеансе

```
$referred_from = $this->session->userdata('referred_from');
```

Получи из сеанса

```
$this->session->userdata('referred_from');
```

Comment: у меня даже сформулировать нормально не получается..())) Спасибо большое!)